# split equation string by multiple delimiters in javascript and keep delimiters then put string back together

Tags: javascript, split, delimiter

I have an equation I want to split by using operators `+`, `-`, `/`, `*` as the delimiters. Then I want to change one item and put the equation back together. For example an equation could be

```
 s="5*3+8-somevariablename/6";
```

I was thinking I could use regular expressions to break the equation apart.

```
    re=/[\+|\-|\/|\*]/g
var elements=s.split(re);
```

Then I would change an element and put it back together. But I have no way to put it back together unless I can somehow keep track of each delimiter and when it was used.  Is there another regexp tool for something like this?

Comment: Use capturing parentheses in your regex and the delimiters end up in the array returned by [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). (According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) not all browsers support this, but I believe the major ones do?)

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on nnnnn's post, this should work:

```
var s = '5*3+8-somevariablename/6';
var regex = /([\+\-\*\/])/;
var a = s.split(regex);

// iterate by twos (each other index)
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i += 2) {
    // modify a[i] here
    a[i] += 'hi';
}

s = a.join(''); // put back together
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also generate regexp dynamically,

```
var s = '5*3+8-somevariablename/6';
var splitter = ['*','+','-','\\/'];
var splitted = s.split(new RegExp('('+splitter.join('|')+')'),'g'));
var joinAgain = a.join('');
```

Here splitted array holds all delimiters because of () given in RegExp